# How would I go about finding the two largest elements in an ArrayList through divide and conquer

Tags: java, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I'm having a lot of figuring out how to do this recursively and through divide and conquer. I thought I had it a while ago, but then what I tried to use didn't work. I have a code that does it through O(n) but it doesn't work because it won't apply to divide and conquer. This is the code for O(n):

```
 public void find(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    for(int n:list){
        if(first < n){
           second = first;
           first = n;
        } else if(second < n){
            second = n;
        }
    }
```

I tried to model this after a quicksort, but then found out that it wouldn't work in a case like `[4,3,6]` where it will just pick 6 after pivoting on the three and immediately eliminate the 4, even though it is the second largest element.

I just need help to do this, I don't need someone to post all the code. I want to try and figure it out by myself, but I'm still having a lot of trouble understanding how to get this done.

Comment: How about in english:  the arrayMax() of a one element array is that one element.  for larger arrays, find the arrayMax() of the first half of the array (up to the middle index) and the arrayMax() of the second half of the array (starting at the middle index) and take the numerical max of those.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wrote up on recursion awhile ago, it should be able to get you started:

---

A recursive method works by breaking a larger problem into smaller problems each time the method is called. This allows you to break what would be a difficult problem; a factorial summation, into a series of smaller problems.

Each recursive function has 2 parts:
1) **The base case**: The lowest value that we care about evaluating. Usually this goes to zero or one.

```
if (num == 1)
  return 0;
```

2) **The general case**: The general case is what we are going to call until we reach the base case. *We call the function again, but this time with 1 less than the previous function started with (indexes to search, values, etc)*. This allows us to work our way towards the base case.

```
return = num + factorial( num - 1);
```

This statement means that we are going to firstly call the function with 1 less than what this function with; we started with three, the next call starts with two, the call after that starts with 1 *(Which triggers our base case!)*

**Once our base case is reached, the methods "recurse-out".** This means they bounce backwards, back into the function that called it, bringing all the data from the functions below it!
It is at this point that our summation actually occurs.

Once the original function is reached, we have our final summation.

For example, let's say you want the summation of the first 3 integers. The first recursive call is passed the number 3.

```
  public static int factorial (int num) {
     //Base case
     if (num == 1) {
        return 1;
     }
  //General case
  return num * factorial(num-1);

  }
```

Walking through the function calls:

```
factorial(3); //Initial function call
```

//Becomes..

```
factorial(1) * factorial(2) * factorial(3) = returned value
```

This gives us a result of 6!

Comment: Yeah I guess I should start with the easy stuff, unfortunately when it comes to recursion I have a wide knowledge gap.

Comment: Recursion is not a trivial concept. It's difficult to understand at times and even harder to master.